# New audit heuristics are needed in Low Quality Posts

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts, code-only-answers

If I remember correctly, the correct action on code-only answers in Low Quality Posts is "Looks OK".

Unfortunately, the review audits in Low Quality Posts don't seem to clearly outline this. All the time I come across people taking "Recommend Deletion" on such answers, and they get deleted so often that I actually resolved to *never finish FP/LA reviews with upvotes or "No Action Needed"*.

So I think that these heuristics should be added to the audit selector (is it even possible/feasible to have one-site-only heuristics for audits?):

- Answers where a large portion (75%+) is recognizable code are ineligible as negative audits, unless they were mod-deleted.
- A new positive audit that takes code-only answers that have decent age and an upvote or two.

Comment: I don't think that the correct action for *all* code-only answers is "Looks OK", or those wouldn't be automatically fed into the LQPQ...?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I know that—the problem is that a fair amount of LQP reviewers seem to think that an answer being code-only is the only reason needed to get it deleted.

Comment: Okay.... I guess I misread your first sentence? Also, I do think that those answers are low quality; maybe not delete-worthy (i.e., not VLQ), but certainly not great, unless they have comments explaining what the code does.